# If an attack that has different effects for living and undead creatures is used on a revenant, what would happen?

Tags: dnd-4e, necromancy, undead

I'm talking specifically about *spirit rend* which for a hit goes: 3d6+ intelligence modifier damage(save ends). If the target is undead, it takes no damage and is not immobilized. Instead, the target must take a free action to move as far as its speed allows to a square farther away from you, and it is dazed(save ends).  One of my PCs used it on his own team member (who was a revenant to try and get him out of a sticky situation. Wondering what should have happened. (let him move away).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**He would be moved away.**

But only if his Wizard fellow considers him an enemy... (see the Target entry for the [Spirit Rend](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13979)<sup>DDI</sup> power).

The [Revenant](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/race.aspx?id=47)<sup>DDI</sup> is, in fact, considered an undead creature because of its Undead trait:

> **Undead:** You are considered an undead creature for the purpose of effects that relate to the undead keyword. You are also considered a living creature.

---

As [Ananisapta](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/2369/ananisapta) correctly pointed out, [Vrylokas](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/race.aspx?id=53)<sup>DDI</sup> (a race of bloodbonded living vampiries introduced in *Heroes of Shadow*) get to choose their creature type according to the whim of the moment:

> **Living Dead:** Because your soul is tainted by undeath, you are both living and undead. If a power has different effects on living creatures and undead creatures, you choose which effect applies to you.

So, while revenants are both undead and living creatures, vrylokas are either one or the other.

Comment: I get it now. For game effects that target undead you count, but you are still alive for more flavor/rpish purposes

Comment: Not only for flavor or story. Some (rare) game effects may refer to a living creature. A revenant is both an undead and a living creature.

Comment: It just seemed quite weird when my assassin rushed into battle, garroted someone, got knocked prone, and then managed to crawl away, the man still being garroted. That might just win the strangest dnd moment of the year award.

Comment: For the sake of completeness - Vryloka, the other both undead and living race, get to choose which one applies.

Comment: Side note: he crawled away because of spirit rend